# Fisher Information & dynamical systems

Tags: information, complex-systems

Preface: I am an ecologist with a barely working background in physics. B.R. Freiden proposes Fisher Information as a unifying  theory of everything (e.g., see books "Physics from Fisher Information", "Science from Fisher Information", "Exploratory Data Analysis Using Fisher Information"). The reviews of these books appear to be mostly critical. Unfortunately for me, these reviews do not touch on the topic of Fisher Information as a measure of order of complex and dynamical systems.

My question is, what is the general consensus of your field or subfields on the FIM as a measure of order of a complex dynamical system? Numerous case studies use FIM and some the Shannon-Fisher product to identify abrupt changes in, e.g., ecological systems and EEG readings.

Comment: The mathematician/physicist John Baez has some recent work about Fisher information in dynamical systems [here](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/information/). There's certainly nothing wrong with that application of it -- the opposition is just towards the 'Fisher information = theory-of-everything' people.

Comment: Thanks, I will check out some of Baez' work. Although the opposition seems to be in the "everything" camp, I do not see FIM used well beyond the same crowd (i.e., lots of self-citations within a small group of peers).

Comment: Maybe loosely related, but from the perspective of quantum information, Fisher information is a measure of multi-particle entanglement. Based on its value you can say how many particles are entangled.

Comment: As I understand it, Fisher information gives a lower bound on the uncertainties of unbiased estimators in statistics. Whether a dynamical system can be studied statistically depends on how well ergodicity is satisfied by its dynamics.